# How to update charts in HighCharts realtime in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, git, github, highcharts

I am using HighCharts in iOS (using HighCharts iOS version https://www.highcharts.com/blog/mobile/).

I want to update my charts dynamically same as is happening in JavaScript (https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update). I am unable to find any methods of documents for the same. Now I doubt Is it even possible with iOS Wrapper?

Please Help..

Comment: Currently you can't use dynamic methods in the wrapper - but it should be possible in the future.